# Docker Toolbox Installation on Windows 7: whale not appearing in terminal

Tags: windows, docker, virtual-machine

Steps followed:

1. Ran the .exe file of docker Toolbox
2. List item
3. Virtualization is enabled already
4. Running as administrator
5. Click on quick start once this is done

Problem detail:

The terminal starts loading and reaches to the point of `docker is up and running` but the whale never appears and neither does the $ symbol.

Specifications:

Windows 7 64 bit HP Pavilion

Comment: type "Docker" in the windows search bar, right click: run as administrator ?

Comment: Yes. That. Could it be because of Firewall or old version of Virtual Box?